# Functions that increment count variables and progress bars on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just learning JavaScript and jQuery, and I've got some code that works, but I know it can be optimized.  I have a page that when a button is clicked it adds 1 to a label, and then increments a bootstrap progress bar by 1. I have 6 functions that could probably be reduced to 2 by passing in arguments instead of having 6 hard coded functions.

Would it be possible to reduce these 6 down to just 1? Also, am I using the `if`/`else` blocks right? Or is there a better way to do that?

Again, I am just learning, but I want to learn the right techniques and formats.

- [Here](https://gist.github.com/greyhammer/369dab30feb9b677c6b2) is a gist if that is easier.
- [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/oaunhfxk/1/) is the jsfiddle as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(addVisit);
    $("#button2").click(removeVisit);
    $("#button3").click(addVisit2);
    $("#button4").click(removeVisit2);
    $("#button5").click(addVisit3);
    $("#button6").click(removeVisit3);
});

function addVisit(){
    var countTag = $('#count');
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent');
    count ++;
    if (count <= 4){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-success');
    } else if (count > 4 && count < 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
    } else if (count >= 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
    }
    countTag.text(count);
    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
}

function removeVisit(){
    var countTag = $('#count');
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent');
    count --;
    if (count <= 4){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-success');
    } else if (count > 4 && count < 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
    } else if (count >= 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
    }
    countTag.text(count);
    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
}

function addVisit2(){
    var countTag = $('#count2');
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent2');
    count ++;
    if (count <= 4){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-success');
    } else if (count > 4 && count < 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
    } else if (count >= 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
    }
    countTag.text(count);
    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
}

function removeVisit2(){
    var countTag = $('#count2');
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent2');
    count --;
    if (count <= 4){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-success');
    } else if (count > 4 && count < 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
    } else if (count >= 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
    }
    countTag.text(count);
    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
}

function addVisit3(){
    var countTag = $('#count3');
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent3');
    count ++;
    if (count <= 4){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-success');
    } else if (count > 4 && count < 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
    } else if (count >= 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
    }
    countTag.text(count);
    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
}

function removeVisit3(){
    var countTag = $('#count3');
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent3');
    count --;
    if (count <= 4){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-success');
    } else if (count > 4 && count < 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
    } else if (count >= 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
    }
    countTag.text(count);
    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Comment: It appears that your code is not working as intended and therefore would not be on-topic for Code Review until it does. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Comment: My apologies,  I misunderstood the title suggestions.  @Phrancis, my code does work, with the hard coded functions.  See the jsfiddle I added.

Comment: Please do not change your code after answers have been posted, in order not to invalidate them. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Phrancis OK, Thanks for the advise. Here is my updated code, for reference. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oaunhfxk/13/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function called `updateProgress` and pass the selector of the progress bar and `count` to it.

```
function updateProgress (selector, count) {
    var progressTag = $(selector); 

    if (count <= 4){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-success');
    } else if (count > 4 && count < 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
    } else if (count >= 8){
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
        progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
        progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
    }
     progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + '%');
}
```

which can be further simplified to

```
function updateProgress (selector, count) {
    var progressTag = $(selector); 

    progressTag.toggleClass('progress-bar-success', count <=4);
    progressTag.toggleClass('progress-bar-warning', count > 4 && count < 8);
    progressTag.toggleClass('progress-bar-danger', count >= 8);

    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + '%');
}
```

You can also have one `addVisit` method, taking an id as parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(addVisit.bind(null, ""));
    $("#button3").click(addVisit.bind(null, "2"));
    $("#button5").click(addVisit.bind(null, "3"));
    // TODO : use the same approach for removeVisit
    $("#button2").click(removeVisit);
    $("#button4").click(removeVisit2);
    $("#button6").click(removeVisit3);
});

function addVisit (id) {

    var countTag = $('#count' + id);
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent' + id);
    // or updateProgress('#percent' + id); 
    //etc
}
```

Ideally though, you would like to have something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".add-btn").click(addVisit);
     $(".remove-btn").click(removeVisit);
 });
```

so that if you need to add another set of buttons and progress to your html the javascript is aleady taken care of.

```
<h1>David Visits&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-default" id="count-david">0</span></h1>
    <div class="progress">
        <div id="percent-david" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-id="david" class="btn add-btn">Add Visit</button>
    <button data-id="david" class="btn remove-btn">Remove Visit</button>
```

So you would need your buttons to have class of `add-btn` and `remove-btn`,
the count and progress to have ids that can be taken from an attribute of the buttons e.g count-david, percent-david, and then `addVisit` might look something like

```
 function addVisit () {
     var btn = $(this);
     var id = btn.attr("data-id"); 

     var countTag = $('#count-' + id); 
     var count = countTag.text();
     var progressTag = $('#percent-' + id);
     // or updateProgress('#percent-' + id); 
     // etc


 }
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Styling and readability

While javascript allows to define strings with single quotes and double quotes, I strongly recommend to use one type, as both types of strings are functionally equivalent. Simply escape single quotes or double quotes based on which type of string you decide to use. Mixing them, such as you did in the following code, will lead to confusing situations where it is unclear where a string starts or ends.

```
progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
```

Reducing the number of functions does not increase the readability of code. Just because you can condense the code down to one function does not mean you have to do this, or that it does make the code more readable. It is more important to make sure that a function does only do one task.

#### Code duplication

Your code has a lot of code duplication. The most obvious case you already pointed out: `addVisit`, `addVisit2` and `addVisit3` are identical except for the identifiers. You could make it a function `addVisit(countId, progressId)`. The click handlers [would need to be adjusted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10000083/2209007).

You partly duplicate the removal of classes. You could push this to the top and only add classes in the if-statement:

```
progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-success');
progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-warning');
progressTag.removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
if (count <= 4){
    progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-success');
} else if (count > 4 && count < 8){
    progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-warning');
} else if (count >= 8){
    progressTag.addClass('progress-bar-danger');
}
```

Speaking of which, that part of the code is identical for both `addVisit` and `removeVisit`. On closer inspection, your `addVisit` and `removeVisit` functions do two things. They modify the count, then they update the progress bar. You could split that in two functions. Think about what you would need to duplicate in case that you, for example, want to add a reset button.

#### Logic errors

Your `addVisit` and `removeVisit` functions do not guard against underflow and overflow. It is perfectly fine to have -3 visits in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your script.

https://jsfiddle.net/mlnmln/6c3ky4ff/

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="content" class="col-md-4">

    <div class="js-Visit">
      <h1>David Visits&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-default js-Visit-count">0</span></h1>
      <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar js-Visit-progressBar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn js-Visit-add">Add Visit</button>
      <button class="btn js-Visit-remove">Remove Visit</button>      
    </div>

    <div class="js-Visit">
      <h1>Joey Visits&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-default js-Visit-count">0</span></h1>
      <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar js-Visit-progressBar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn js-Visit-add">Add Visit</button>
      <button class="btn js-Visit-remove">Remove Visit</button>      
    </div>

    <div class="js-Visit">
      <h1>Times CS Leaves Early for no Reason&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label label-default js-Visit-count">0</span></h1>
      <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar js-Visit-progressBar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn js-Visit-add">Add Early Leave</button>
      <button class="btn js-Visit-remove">Remove Early Leave</button>      
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  var defaults = {
    min: 0, 
    max: 10, 
    count: 0    
  };

  function Visit(element, options) {
    this.element = element;            
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;      
    this.view = {
      count: this.element.find('.js-Visit-count'), 
      progressBar: this.element.find('.js-Visit-progressBar')
    };
    this.init();
  };

  Visit.prototype = {

    init: function() {      
      this.element.on('click', '.js-Visit-add', $.proxy(this.add, this));
      this.element.on('click', '.js-Visit-remove', $.proxy(this.remove, this));      
    }, 

    setOption: function(key, value) {
      if (key === 'count') {
        value = Math.max(this.options.min, Math.min(this.options.max, value));
      }
      this.options[key] = value;
      this.render();
    }, 

    add: function() {
      this.setOption('count', this.options.count + 1);
    }, 

    remove: function() {
      this.setOption('count', this.options.count - 1);      
    }, 

    render: function() {
      this.view.count.text(this.options.count);
      this.view.progressBar.css('width', this.options.count / this.options.max * 100 + '%');        
      this.states = [
        {
          test: this.options.count <= 4, 
          className: 'progress-bar-success'
        }, 
        {
          test: this.options.count > 4 && this.options.count < 8, 
          className: 'progress-bar-warning'
        }, 
        {
          test: this.options.count >= 8, 
          className: 'progress-bar-danger'
        }
      ];      

      for (var i = 0; i < this.states.length; i++) {
        var state = this.states[i];          
        this.view.progressBar.toggleClass(state.className, state.test);
      } 
    }    
  };


  $(function() {    
    $('.js-Visit').each(function() {
        new Visit($(this));    
    });
  });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

## Major Concerns

### Code duplication

`addVisit`, `addVisit2`, `addVisit3` are essentially the same, but with different identifiers. This is a clear sign that they could be condensed into one function which accepts parameters.

### Global scope pollution

Your are polluting the global variable scope. By default all variables live on the global `window` object. Because of possible naming conflicts with other libraries this is considered bad practice. An Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) protects against that.

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) { 
  // ... 
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

### Missing overflow/underflow protection

Your counter is not protected against underflow and overflow. This can easily be fixed using `Math.min` and `Math.max`.

```
value = Math.max(this.options.min, Math.min(this.options.max, value));
```

## Minor Concerns

- `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` can be written as `$(function() { ... })`

PS: I did a complete rewrite and I don't have the time to explain everything I did now, but I will gladly answer upcoming questions.